# One data result requires leading zero (MYSQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql

I have sorted data that has a column (varchar (5)) containing data 4 characters long - except one, which is 3 characters long.  So it doesn't sort numerically. What I need is 0200, but what is listed in the database is 200.  This is what it's supposed to look like:

```
 0200
 111X
 2222
 3333
```

This is what it looks like:

```
111X
200
2222
3333
```

How do a add the leading zero to only this numeric rather than to the whole field so that it sorts the 200 before the 111X?

Comment: you mean to want to update the data in the table, or just pad it on-the-fly for use in a query? Fixing the source data would probably make more sense, really.

Comment: Thanks. Source data is in MYSQL, but as I can't update the number in the table due to foreign key constraints I have to update it in the query.

Comment: In that case see Krish's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LPAD` function to pad values

select LPAD('200',4,0); => `0200`

Sample select

```
Select
    LPAD(TheField,4,0) as FieldName
FROM
    YourTable
Order By 1; -- position of the field
```

Comment: Thanks Krish.  I  am not sure where to apply this in my code:    `               
                                                                                                                     
`SELECT 
Book_Code,
Book_Title AS 'Title',
Branch_Num,
Copy_Num,
Copy_Quality AS 'Quality',
Copy_Price AS 'Price'
FROM BOOK
JOIN COPY USING (Book_Code)
JOIN BRANCH USING (Branch_Num)
WHERE Book_Type = 'FIC';`

Comment: When I add your code it just shows the result of 0200 only.  But I need it to update the field just like my example so that the query sorts the data correctly.

Comment: @ppines have you tried `order by lpad(yourfield,4,0)`